# Most complicated proof of Pythagoras

Tags: soft-question, alternative-proof

Usually a mathematician aims for clarity and elegance when conducting a proof. However, the antimathematician buries all hope of assimilating intuition and reasoning. To illustrate this, I seek the most complicated and/or long-winded proof of the beloved Pythagorean theorem. It doesmt have to be War and Peace or Paradise Lost, but length is always appreciated.

Comment: An unusual question!  I was thinking of voting to close this, but you've intrigued me.

Comment: There are 117 proofs here. Search for your unfavorite: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/

Comment: Let $\phi$ be Pythagoras' Theorem and let $\psi$ be a statement, all of whose currently known proofs are insanely long and complicated. Then any proof of $\psi \wedge \phi$ is a a proof of Pythagoras' Theorem and (at least currently) insanely long and complicated.

Comment: What could be more fun than venting your frustration at the proof of something you learned in Euclidean geometry?

Comment: @Stefan Hah! I was just about to suggest the same thing with $\psi = \text{Fermat's Last Theorem}$! That's going to be pretty involved to say the least.

Comment: What is an 'anti-poet'? Someone who destroys poetry like matter and anti-matter, perhaps. In which case anti-mathematics might be characterized as disproving a theorem. Or perhaps anti-mathematics requires a non-mathematical definition.

Comment: The title mentions "complicated" but the body introduces "long-winded" as an alternative.  This suggests that however long one proof is, there exists another that is longer.  How long is long enough?  One might even entertain the notion of an infinitely long proof, for extended logics that allow such things, and consider the possibility of a proof of uncountably infinite length.  Many would consider such a proof to be no proof at all, so perhaps the Question admits a Schrödinger's catalog of proofs, each longer than the others except when a Reader inspects one.

Answer (score 7):

I love the challenge.

1. $e^z=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{z^n}{n!}$ defines an entire function over the complex plane.
    By convolutions we have $e^z\cdot e^{w}=e^{z+w}$ for any $z,w\in\mathbb{C}$;
2. The elementary trigonometric functions can be defined, for any $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$, as $\sin\theta=\text{Im } e^{i\theta}$ and $\cos\theta=\text{Re }e^{i\theta}$. This is equivalent to the standard definition since the map $\theta\mapsto \cos\theta+i\sin\theta = e^{i\theta}$ gives a parametrization of $S^1$ with constant speed: the speed is constant since $\frac{d}{dz}e^z=e^z$ is a trivial consequence of termwise differentiation of the series defining $e^z$;
3. It is a parametrization of $S^1$ since for any $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$ we have
   $$ \|e^{i\theta}\|^2 = e^{i\theta}\cdot \overline{e^{i\theta}} = e^{i\theta}\cdot e^{\overline{i\theta}} = e^{i\theta}\cdot e^{-i\theta} = e^0 = 1.$$
4. In terms of $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$, the last identity takes the form
   $$(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)(\cos\theta-i\sin\theta)=\color{red}{\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta = 1}$$
   which is the Pythagorean theorem.