# New proof of Pythagorean identity

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification, proof-writing

We know that $$e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$$Substituting $x\mapsto-x$: $$e^{-ix}=\cos x-i\sin x$$Multiplying the two equations: $$\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1$$Is this a new proof of the Pythagorean identity that doesn't have any circular reasoning? I believe so since Euler's formula can be proved using the Taylor series, which I don't think has any relation with the Pythagorean theorem. But I want to make sure.

I got this proof when I was trying to find $\cos(i)$ on my own.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2549714/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3644869/42969

Comment: @MartinR Which is to say, it's not new. But it is undoubtedly cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't really a *proof* at all.

This is because Euler deliberately choose to arbitrarily (and artificially) **define** $~e^{i\theta}~$ as $~\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta).~$

That is, $~e^{i\theta}~$ was intentionally defined to provide **syntactic sugar** for the expression $~\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta).~$

Euler relied on the fact that then $~e^{i\alpha} \times e^{i\beta} = e^{i(\alpha + \beta)}.$

Further, Euler noticed that (it could be argued) the definition makes sense because:

- You can start with the Taylor series of the Sine function, and multiply the entire series by the scalar $~i = \sqrt{-1}.$
- You can also use the Taylor series for Cosine of $x.$
- Combining the two, you can compare the combination to the Taylor Series for $~e^x,~$ where you substitute $~ix~$ for $~x.$

Comment: Amazing rep coincidence! Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @KamalSaleh, you accepted the answer so give it a +1.

Comment: @user25406 I did :) I am assuming that the first two points aren't valid since the Taylor series was originally not defined for real numbers. Is that right?

Comment: @KamalSaleh You have it backwards.  The Taylor series was originally defined for real numbers rather than Complex numbers.  This applies to the Sine function, the Cosine function, and the function $~f(x) = e^x.$

Comment: @KamalSaleh Notice that in my answer, I just found and corrected an analytical error.  Euler took the entire Taylor series of the Sine function and multiplied it by the scalar $~i = \sqrt{-1}.$

Comment: @user2661923 I meant complex numbers. Oops.